Docker Swarm: Get IP Address of containers
I need your support.
I am building up a business network on a VPS, and I'm using Docker Swarm.
In the Swarm environment, there will be a Wireguard VPN service, a DNS server and a bunch of other services that needs to be accessed only through VPN. Here is my file:
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  wireguard_data:
  gitlab_data:
  gitlab_logs:
  gitlab_config:
  traefik-certificates:
  
networks:
    vpn:
        name: vpn
        driver: overlay
        ipam:
          config:
            - subnet: 10.0.1.0/24
services:
    wg-easy:
        environment:
          - LANG=it
          # ⚠️ Required:
          # Change this to your host's public address
          - WG_HOST=localhost

          # Optional:
          - PASSWORD=admin
          # - PASSWORD_HASH=$$2y$$10$$hBCoykrB95WSzuV4fafBzOHWKu9sbyVa34GJr8VV5R/pIelfEMYyG (needs double $$, hash of 'foobar123'; see "How_to_generate_an_bcrypt_hash.md" for generate the hash)
          # - PORT=51821
          # - WG_PORT=51820
          # - WG_CONFIG_PORT=92820
          - WG_DEFAULT_ADDRESS=10.0.2.x
          - WG_DEFAULT_DNS=dns.example.com
          # - WG_MTU=1420
          - WG_ALLOWED_IPS=10.0.1.0/24
          # - WG_PERSISTENT_KEEPALIVE=25
          - WG_PRE_UP=iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
          - WG_POST_DOWN=iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -d 10.0.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
          - UI_TRAFFIC_STATS=true
          - UI_CHART_TYPE=1 # (0 Charts disabled, 1 # Line chart, 2 # Area chart, 3 # Bar chart)

        image: ghcr.io/wg-easy/wg-easy
        container_name: wg-easy
        hostname: 'vpn.example.com'
        depends_on:
            - dnsmasq
        volumes:
          - wireguard_data:/etc/wireguard
        networks:
          - vpn
        ports:
          - "51820:51820/udp"
          - "51821:51821/tcp"
        restart: unless-stopped
        cap_add:
          - NET_ADMIN
          - SYS_MODULE
          # - NET_RAW # ⚠️ Uncomment if using Podman 
        sysctls:
          - net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
          - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
        deploy:
          replicas: 1
          labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.udp.routers.wireguard.entrypoints=wireguard"
            - "traefik.udp.services.wireguard.loadbalancer.server.port=51820"
            - "traefik.http.routers.wireguard-ui.rule=Host(`vpn.example.com`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.wireguard-ui.entrypoints=web"
            - "traefik.http.services.wireguard-ui.loadbalancer.server.port=51821"
    dnsmasq:
        image: dockurr/dnsmasq
        container_name: dnsmasq
        hostname: 'dns.example.com'
        environment:
          DNS1: "1.0.0.1"
          DNS2: "1.1.1.1"
        networks:
          - vpn
        volumes:
          - ./configs/dnsmasq.conf:/etc/dnsmasq.conf
        restart: unless-stopped
        cap_add:
          - NET_ADMIN
        deploy:
          replicas: 1
          labels:
            - "traefik.enable=false"
    gitlab:
        image: gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
        container_name: gitlab
        restart: always
        hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
        volumes:
          - gitlab_data:/var/opt/gitlab
          - gitlab_logs:/var/log/gitlab
          - gitlab_config:/etc/gitlab
        shm_size: '256m'
        #environment:
            #GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
            #    # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
            #    external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
        networks:
            - vpn
        deploy:
          replicas: 1
          labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.rule=Host(`gitlab.example.com`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.entrypoints=web"
            - "traefik.http.services.gitlab.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
    whoami:
        image: traefik/whoami
        container_name: whoami
        restart: always
        hostname: 'whoami.example.com'
        networks:
            - vpn
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            labels:
                - "traefik.enable=true"
                - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.example.com`)"
                - "traefik.http.services.whoami.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
    traefik:
        image: traefik:latest
        command:
          - "--providers.docker=true"
          - "--api.dashboard=true"
          - "--log.level=INFO"
          #- "--log.filepath=/var/log/traefik.log
          - "--accesslog=true"
          #- "--accesslog.filepath=/var/log/traefik-access.log
          - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
          - "--providers.docker.network=vpn"
          - "--providers.swarm.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
          - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
          - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
          - "--entrypoints.dns.address=:53"
          - "--entrypoints.wireguard.address=:51820/udp"
          - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=false"
          - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=your-email@example.com"
          - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
          - traefik-certificates:/letsencrypt
        networks:
            - vpn
        deploy:
          #mode: global
          labels:
            - traefik.enable=true
            - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.example.com`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"
            - "traefik.http.services.dummy-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=9999"

As you can see, I'm using DNSMasq to redirect all instances of "example.com" to the Traefik reverse proxy, and I need to configure the DNSMasq instance as default DNS for Wireguard VPN Clients (WG_DEFAULT_DNS variable), but it seems I cannot retrieve IP Addresses of these containers.
The ideal solution would be:

Start Traefik instance, so Swarm assign it an IP in the network (e.g. 10.0.1.100)
Start DNSMasq, passing the IP address of Traefik, so I can configure dnsmasq.conf accordingly (address=/example.com/10.0.1.100). Swarm assign to DNSMasq container an IP (e.g. 10.0.1.2)
Start Wireguard VPN, passing the IP Address of DNSMasq as WG_DEFAULT_DNS variable (e.g. WG_DEFAULT_DNS=10.0.1.2)

Obviously, the order will be managed by depends_on directive, so I'll be sure Wireguard starts once DNSMasq started, and this one starts once Traefik instance started.
With a configuration like that, I'm totally sure that I do not need to reconfigure anything in case of restart/outage/change of IP Addresses.
Is this configuration possible? If I am wrong with some, if not all, of the concepts, please guide me in the right direction to achieve the same objective. I also thought about making DNSMasq as system service on host, instead of Docker Swarm, but I'll still need the Traefik IP to redirect correctly.
Thanks in advance

When using Docker Swarm with multiple nodes, you would usually deploy with docker stack deploy, which does not support depends_on. But you should be able to set a fixed IP for a single service instance and also set a DNS IP.

@bluepuma77 not really. In Docker Swarm the usually used Network driver Is overlay, and it doesn't support setting a static IP, instead of bridge driver, which is unfortunately not suitable for Docker Swarm

once traffic is inside swarm why is dnsmasq needed? Just use the overlay routing mesh. Services inside the swarm should not need to resolve or use *.example.com addresses - the only dns that needs example.com should be outside the swarm and point at the swarm nodes.

@ChrisBecke thanks. So what are you saying is that is only needed an A record on DNS pointing to example.com and subdomains, and Traefik, with the internal Swarm routing, will do the rest? I thought a DNS server was required, as I have to indicate it to Wireguard as DNS to use when connected. Plus, that's mandatory that services needs to be accessed only when connected to VPN, and should respond to .example.com

You have requirements that are difficult to understand in the limited context afforded by comments. But I will say that Traefik does not need to resolve "foo.example.com" if that is what some swarm service claims (via a traefik Host* rule) to serve.
